# Mutable, indexed sequence for a large amount of integers in Scala?

Tags: list, scala, sequence

So, if I want to store 5 zeros in a sequence, and access them later through their index numbers, what type of a sequence should I use in Scala?

In Python i would do something like this:

```
listTest = list(0,0,0,0,0)
listTest[1] = 3
print(listTest)

-> 0,3,0,0,0
```

I realize a similar question is likely already answered to. Might be that I just don't know the right keywords to find one.

Comment: An https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/mutable/ArrayBuffer.html or a plain https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/Array.html would do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Collections performance characteristics](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/collections-2.13/performance-characteristics.html) lists among others the following sequences that are mutable, and indexable in **constant** time

```
ArrayBuffer
ArraySeq
Array
```

Note how the document refers to indexing as **applying**. The reason for this is that in Scala element is accessed via `apply` method like so

```
val arr = ArrayBuffer(11, 42, -1)
arr.apply(1) // 42 
arr(1)       // sugared version of arr.apply(1) so also evaluates to 42
```

To decide which one to use consider

- [What is the difference between ArrayBuffer and Array](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31213983/5205022)
- [Array vs ArraySeq](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5029236/5205022)

---

As a side-note, Python's `list` is conceptually different from Scala's `List` because former is array-based indexed collection with constant-time indexing, whilst latter is **linked** list collection with linear-time indexing.